# How secure is file header encryption for large files?

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption

I'm having trouble location information about whether or not encrypting a file's header is *good enough*. The files in question are media files that range in size from 500mb to 4GB.

If I had no performance or time constraints, I would simply encrypt the entirety with AES256. However, with my current implementation (in `C#`), it takes about 3 minutes to decrypt a 2GB file. This is about 2m45s beyond my time limits.

How vulnerable is that file's contents without the file header?

Apologies if this question is silly, this is my first foray into file security.

Comment: 1) What are your security goals? Encrypting only part of the file will not be acceptable under most security goals. 2) A desktop computer should be able to get under 15s as long as IO keeps up.

Comment: Basic security to discourage attempts to use the file. It would be ideal if the entire file could be encrypted but the time to decrypt cannot exceed 15s, so I find myself limited. I also considered some sort of hybrid encryption - AES256 file header and something very fast (and less secure) for the remainder of the file.

Comment: 1) On my computer C#'s `AesCryptoService` provider takes about 15s for 2GB when using AES128. If you're willing to use native interop you should be able to speed that up a lot, especially if it uses AES-NI. 2) If performance matters, use AES-128 not AES-256. It's still very secure and about 1.4 times faster.

Comment: You might consider replacing your AES implementation with a better (faster) one; as CodesInChaos says, a fast AES implementation should be able to run a lot faster than > 1 minute per Gigabyte.

Comment: I expect disk I/O to be the limiting factor. I have tested 2 libraries (Bouncy Castle, SharpAesCrypt) and will now test with .NET AesCryptoProvider which is fully unmanaged and might provide better performance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That only your application can play these video files?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: @Erode Then why do you need such a high performance? A 2GB file will contain a video *far* longer than 15s or even 3m, so decryption cost should be negligible compared to the video decoding cost.

Comment: They are stored locally and the video player library in use does not support streaming a partial file. However, I am willing to investigate the possibility of adding that capability. FYI, I did get good performance from `AesCryptoProvider` - decrypted 4GB in 25 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format. The size suggests it is a video. However, video formats seems to be designed to be seekable. That means, the attacker seems to be able to:

1. Create some header (guessing the resolution and some other information)
2. If the beginning was damaged, play and seek in the file.

Comment: Yes, the files are videos. I am mainly concerned that merely encrypting the file *header* would leave the actual video content vulnerable to a savvy individual who knew, or could guess the file format. So it would appear that partial encryption may not be viable.